# How does the 1-Lipschitz and uniform boundedness matter in establishing this as a metric?

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Given $\mu, \nu \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ the space of positive measures on $\mathbb{R}$ we want to show that

$$ d(\mu, \nu) = \sup_{|f|\leq 1\\ f \ 1-\text{Lipschitz}}\left|\int f d\mu - \int fd\nu \right|$$

is a metric on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. It doesn't seem to me like the functions' properties are needed anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: If your question is if it is necessary for the supremum to only be over Lipschitz $f$ for $d$ to be a metric, then no, this is not required. Exercise - show that w/o the Lipschitz condition, the $d$ you get is (essentially) total variation distance. The Wasserstein distance above introduces a Lipschitz condition to emphasise (and de-emphasise) certain aspects of the difference between $\mu$ and $\nu$ as compared to TV. Further, replacing that by a different, sufficiently rich class of functions would give you another distance (for an exotic example, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.00573.pdf ).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 This comment would be a very good answer; better than the one we have now.

Answer (score 0):

To show that d is a metric you will have to show that $\int f d\mu=\int f d\nu$ for every 1-Lipschtz function f implies $\mu =\nu$. (Since both sides are linear in f the value of the Lipschitz constant doesn't matter). A very detailed argument would be lengthy so I will give a sketch. Let C be a compact set and $D=\{x :d(x,C) \geq 1/n\}$. Let $f_n(x)=\frac {d(x,D)} {d(x,C)+d(x,D)}$. Verify that this is indeed a Lipschtiz function. (This is a bit lengthy but some simple algebraic manipulation will give this).  Show that $f_n \to I_C$ pointwise and apply DCT to see that $\mu (C)=\nu (C)$. Since C is arbitrary we get $\mu= \nu$

Comment: I suppose you mean $D_n = \{x: d(x, C) \geq 1/n \}$ and $f_n$ modified accordingly. That $f_n$ are continuous is clear. That $d(x, D)$ is 1-Lipschitz is also clear but could you provide some details about the Lipschitz condition on $f_n$?

Comment: Consider $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|$ and simplify. In the numerator add and subtract $d(y,C)d(y,D_n)$ and split into two terms. You should now be able to  get $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \leq \alpha d(x,y)$ where $\alpha = \frac 2 {d(x,C)+d(x,D_n)}$. To make sure that $alpha$ stays away from 0 you will need the fact $d(C,D_n) >0$. This is where we need C to be compact. [ I had earlier taken C to be any closed set but  you don't get Lispchitz property  if $d(C,D_n)=0$]. I hope  youcan work through this with these hints.