# The Lipschitz constant of the combination of distance functions used to separate two sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Given closed, disjoint sets $C, D$ in a metric space $(X, d)$, we define
$f: X \to \mathbb{R} $ by $$x \mapsto \dfrac{d(x, D)}{d(x, D) + d(x, C)}$$

I know that $d(x, C)$ and $d(x, D)$ are $1$-Lipschitz and that $f$ is continuous. I am having trouble showing that $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz (I suspect it is but not sure).

Comment: This shouldn't be 1-Lipschitz without further conditions. For intuition - imagine $\mathbb{R}^2$ and suppose $C$ and $D$ are close together. Connect two 'closest points' in $C$ and in $D$. Then the function has to go from $1$ to $0$ in the distance along this line. But this line can be arbitrarily small if the separation between $C$ and $D$ is not controlled. For instance, if $C = \{(x,y): x \le -a\}, D = \{(x,y): x \ge a\},$ then $d( (-a, 0), (a,0)) = 2a$ and $f(-a, 0) - f(a,0) = 1,$ and so for $a < 1/2,$ $1$-Lipschitz-ness is violated.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 If we impose one of them be compact and $X$ be Euclidean? It still won't be **1** Lipschitz though right?

Comment: Make the half spaces into rectangles, doesn't change the argument at all. Really, if $d(C,D)$ is not controlled in *some* way, then you really cannot say anything at all.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 My question was based on looking at this post and attempting to solve this. As the answerer establishes, the function is in fact Lipschitz under the additional conditions but the constant remains an issue as far as I can see. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670023/how-does-the-1-lipschitz-and-uniform-boundedness-matter-in-establishing-this-as/2670291?noredirect=1#comment5518239_2670291

Comment: $d(C,D_n)$ controlled in the post linked

Comment: It is Lipschitz if one of the sets is compact or just $d(C,D)>0$. I have just posted lots of hints for this at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670023/how-does-the-1-lipschitz-and-uniform-boundedness-matter-in-establishing-this-as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the distance between two sets, $\rho:=d(C, D)$, is positive, the function $f$ is Lipschitz with the constant $1/\rho$. This constant cannot be improved, since $f=0$ on $D$ and $f=1$ on $C$.  (For the same reason, $f$ is not Lipschitz when $\rho=0$.)

Proof. Let $Z$ be the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the maximum norm, $\|(u, v)\|_\infty = \max(|u|, |v|)$. The function $f$ is the composition of two maps,
$$
g:X\to Z, \qquad  g(x)= (d(x, C), d(x, D)) 
$$
and 
$$
h:Z\to \mathbb{R}, \qquad  h(u, v) = \frac{v}{u+v} 
$$
Thus, the Lipschitz constant of $f$ is at most the Lipschitz constant of $g$ times the Lipschitz constant of $h$.

The triangle inequality implies that $g$ is $1$-Lipschitz (this is why the maximum norm is used there; Euclidean would be a little wasteful). So it remains to estimate the Lipschitz constant  of $h$ on the range of $g$. The range of $g$ is contained in the set
$$
P = \{(u, v) : u\ge 0, \ v\ge 0, \ u+v\ge \rho\}
$$

**Lemma**: the Lipschitz constant of a differentiable function on a convex subset of a normed linear space $Z$ is the supremum of the $Z^*$-norm of its gradient.  (Note: the gradient of a function on $Z$ takes values in  the dual space $Z^*$.)

Proof of the lemma: the mean value theorem says $f(p)-f(q) = \langle \nabla f(\xi), p-q\rangle$ for some $\xi$ between $p$ and $q$. Here the angle brackets denote dual pairing, and $|\langle \nabla f(\xi), p-q\rangle|\le \|\nabla f(\xi)\|_{Z^*}\|p-q\|_Z$ by the definition of dual norm. $\quad\Box$

Going back to our $h$, compute 
$$
\nabla h(u, v) = \left( \frac{-v}{(u+v)^2}, \frac{u}{(u+v)^2} \right)
$$
The dual to the maximum norm is the $1$-norm $\|(\alpha, \beta)\|_1 = |\alpha|+|\beta|$. Since
$$
\|\nabla h(u, v)\|_1  =  \frac{v}{(u+v)^2} + \frac{u}{(u+v)^2} = \frac{1}{u+v} \le \frac{1}{\rho}
$$
for every $(u, v)$ in $P$, the claim is proved.